# Dynamics CRM Email entity isReply, isForward replacement in 2013/2015?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, xrm, xrmservicetoolkit

In Dynamics CRM 2015 Email forms I need to know if email is forwarded, replied etc.
In Dynamics CRM 2011 there used to be JavaScript variables for this e.g. isReply, isForward, isReplyall

These variables doesn't exists in Dynamics CRM 2013/2015. 
Is there any alternative to get this information on email form?

Regards
Imran

Comment: We were checking Email subject contains RE: or FW: at the beginning to verify.

Comment: We did that too, not the robust solution specially when your environment is multilingual...

Answer (score 0):

We have to read the subject line of email to see `RE:` `FW:`

In addition to that CRM tracking token will be appended at the end of email subject.

If you want to configure for multilingual, use some config to have all the equivalent of `RE:` `FW:` of your user base languages in a delimited string to check.